# Firebase third party php wrapper

Tags: firebase

I am trying to use firebase with PHP by using the third party wrapper they recommend:
https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php

However, I am not having any luck. I just need a simple way to add data to my firebase. How do I do this?

Comment: Hi Jared, what do you mean by "not having any luck"? Could you please describe your problem(s) in more detail so that people may get a clue about what your problem could be?

Comment: Jared, I'm the creator of the Firebase PHP library. Please let me know if you have any questions (be more specific), I'm glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

There is another version that is simple to implement and handy that I have created in github using the elements from this author.

You will just need to do the following configs:

```
$url =  'https://my-custom-project.firebaseio.com/';
$token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
```

Once the config is done

```
//Initializing the object
$fboject = new FirebaseFunctions($url, $token);
```

Define the Path and then you will be able to add your JSON data into the path using various operations that have been implemented in the class.

Here I have implemented it for courses

```
//Path Set for Adding - This should be changed for different operations
$fboject->path = "/courses";

//Add JSON to firebase
$fboject->addData($json);

//Retrieve the added data from firebase
$added_data = $fboject->getData();
```

Update course number 2 at position 1 since array indexing is from 0-9 for 10 listings

1. Create an updated JSON.
2. Set the course path to the "/courses/1" that
   corresponds to the second course in firebase.

   $fboject->path = "/courses/1";
   $fboject->updateData($updated_json);

Delete course number 10 at position 9 since array indexing is from 0-9 for 10 listings, set the course path to the "/courses/9" that corresponds to the last course in firebase.

```
$fboject->path = "/courses/9";
$fboject->deleteData();
```

The link to the github is given below and detailed explanation is there too on it.

Comment: You should not post "link only" answers here, because they loose its usefulness if linked resource is no longer available. It would be best to summarize your solution and provide code snippet presenting it if possible